# Is it possible to grant tenant-specific app-only tokens for O365 API / Azure AD apps?

Tags: api, azure, office365, oauth-2.0

Working off [pages like this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/#comment-7275), I have a "service/daemon" test app working with the O365 mail REST API: i give consent to the app, an app-only token is granted via a X.509-signed client assertion, and i can read info from an arbitrary mailbox. It works great.

But our app will be installed for various clients on their private machines -- so it's like a native app, but we need the global permissions that app-only tokens are required for (which is why we aren't a native app).

Since access tokens are granted only based on our app credentials, i think they won't work for us: Customer A could get an access token for Customer B's private data using just the app credentials and the Azure AD tenant ID.

**Is there any way to "require client secret for app-only token generation and restrict calls to this tenant ID"? I could then make a secret key for each customer.**

Or if a cert could be restricted to a particular tenant ID, we could make a separate cert for each customer.

Having each customer define an app of their own isn't a realistic option, as it's far too complicated for them, requires cert generation, editing the manifest, etc etc.

Maybe there is a back-door way to get app-only style global access with a 'native app' architecture? E.g. if our customer has an admin account, could we authenticate with the 'native app' style oauth grant for that one admin user, and access all users' email via that account's permissions?

Comment: Seeing this: https://www.cogmotive.com/blog/office-365-tips/grant-full-access-to-all-mailboxes-in-office-365

...i see that admin users can be delegated full access; is it simpler these days? And would the API calls work (e.g. /users/somebody@domain.com/MailFolders/inbox/messages) or does that only work through the GUI?